# How to determine if a path is located on a physical device or in memory?

Tags: linux

I am looking for a way to know, programmatically, if a path point to a physical device or in memory.

I have noticed that the `du` command print a size of zero for paths in `/sys` or `/proc` for example, but I am not sure if this is a reliable because I think a file on a disk can have a size of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easily possible because of the philosophy (one filesystem with mountpoints, network transparency, everything is a file (or folder)) used in linux. Imagine: a network file system mounted into your system. It is not in any physical device of your computer - is this physical or not?

The only *heuristic* that comes to mind is comparing the filesystem against a predefined list: check the output of `mount`, e.g.:

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=204096k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

the first column is the source device - on the first entry there is no device geiven, just the virtual filesystem `tmpfs` whereas in the second entry we see a proper device `/dev/sda2`.

a device is no guarantee for physical storage, there is `/dev/mem` for example, which gives direct access to the computers' memory.

So, my suggestion is to find out which  mountpoint applies to a path (try `lsblk`), find that mountpoint in the output of `mount`. If this mountpoint does not match a device int the form of `/dev/WHATEVER` assume it is in-memory

Using the suggestion from @Chris, try e.g. this `findmnt -T /proc/net/stat/arp_cache`:

```
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/proc  proc   proc   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
```

The relavant columns is `SOURCE`

Comment: I agree filesystem type is your best best. For parsing results with a script, `findmnt` is much easier than `mount`. It has a lot of options for controlling what to output, and how.

Comment: oooh nice, didn't know that one